# Does Skoran survive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

At the end of "Thine Own Self," Skoran impales Data with a metal rod. This causes Data to shut down, and Skoran to be electrocuted. The latter screams in pain.

Does anything speak to Skoran's fate? Did he die?

[image]

Comment: I'm more interested in exactly why Data's innards have that much voltage to earth.

Answer (score 1):

## He probably does survive

Looking through several sources, the scene in question is described as follows:

> -- Finally, Skoran rushes up and DRIVES a spear through
>   Data's back, IMPALING him on the metal rod.
>
> -- Data begins to jerk and there is a **small SPRAY OF
>   SPARKS from where he was stabbed**.

([Source](http://antoa.com/tng/))

No mention of Skoran being injured

---

> (Data pours the compound into the well just as Skoran impales him and **gets an electric shock for his effort**. Data falls as Talur arrives)

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/268.htm))

So this indicates that Skoran *was* electrocuted, but we still don't know how significantly this impacted him.

---

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_%28episode%29) describes the scene as follows:

> **The blacksmith is shocked with electricity** and Data collapses onto the ground, the pole going through his torso.

Skoran's page on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Skoran) doesn't indicate he died from it.

Another important point is to consider Data's creation was after Lore's.  Data was created with the intention to **not harm beings** after Lore began malfunctioning.  Considering the details Dr Soong added to minimise harm to humans (e.g. installation of a flotation device in Data), it stands to reason that Data had a device installed to minimise any electric shocks delivered to individuals should his circuits be damaged.

Admittedly, it has been a while since I've seen the episode, but I don't recall seeing Skoran fall from the shock.  If the shock had been sufficient to kill Skoran, it would have done so there and then.  We see Data fall, **but not Skoran**.  I think then that Skoran **probably did not die from the electric shock**.